# Problem uploading code to ESP 8266-01 adapter

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266

I feel like I've tried just about everything and it still doesn't work. There must be something I'm not seeing. I am using an Arduino uno, an ESP8266-01 wifi module, and an [ESP-01 Adapter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6rmp.jpg). The arduino is connected to the laptop, and I'm using 4 AA batteries as external source (they are brand new) because I wanted to check if my Arduino wasn't supplying the necessary power.

I keep getting the following error:
warning: espcomm_sync failed
error: espcomm_open failed
error: espcomm_upload_mem failed
error: espcomm_upload_mem failed

I changed my preferences to add to the boards http://arduino.esp8266.com/versions/2.4.1/package_esp8266com_index.json

This is how I set up tools. I keep trying every upload speed whenever I make a change to see if that makes it work but nothing still.

[image: Board: Generic ESP 8266 Module.]

I also tried using [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ao5XcORsYxA) tutorial but it also didn't work.

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: using Uno instead of USBtoTTL adapter is a workaround that doesn't work with some Unos

Comment: Try this: [https://tttapa.github.io/Pages/Arduino/ESP8266/Flashing/Flashing-With-an-Arduino.html](https://tttapa.github.io/Pages/Arduino/ESP8266/Flashing/Flashing-With-an-Arduino.html)

Comment: I tried it but it still didn't work. Has anyone actually build that themselves? like... any tips? I feel like I followed the instructions by the letter.

Comment: @KennethYoung, you think Pieter (tttapa) wrote it in the tutorial without trying?

Comment: @Juraj well, the idea was to ask if anyone that did it had any tips, like common problems or easy to miss details or something

Comment: I tried it for fun it and it didn't work at all. And I am an experienced troubleshooter. I tested with Seeeduino Lotus with CH340 and with Uno WiFi which in this case should be equivalent to original Uno R3 Made in Italy with ATmega16U2. But normally I use an USBtoTTL adapter to program an esp8266 module.